# How to convert "like each" into a functional form?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a column of a table whose data type is a character array. I want to pass in a functional select where clause, where the column is in a list of given strings. However, I cannot simply use `` (in; `col; myList) `` for reasons. Instead, I need to do the equivalent of:

```
max col like/: myList
```

which effectively gives the same result. However, I have tried to put this in functional form

```
(max; (like/:; `col; myList))
```

And I am getting a type error. Any ideas on how I could make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice trick when dealing with this problem is using `parse` on a string of the select statement you want to functionalize.  For example:

```
q)parse"select from t where max col like/: myList"
?
`t
,,(max;((/:;like);`col;`myList))
0b
()
```

Or specifically in your case you want the 3rd element of the result list (the where clause):

```
q)(parse"select from t where max col like/: myList")2
max ((/:;like);`col;`myList)
```

I even think using this pattern in your actual code can be a good idea, as functionalized statements like `` max ((/:;like);`col;`myList) `` can get pretty unreadable pretty quickly!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

it should be: `` (max;((/:;like);`col;`mylist)) ``

Answer (score 1):

```
(any; ((/:;like); `col; enlist,myList))
```